How to create a TypeScript class constructor with multiple generics for each parameter?
I'm building a TypeScript class that needs to accept multiple parameters of the type EscapeHandlerSettings.
type EscapeHandlerSettings<
  E extends string,
  N extends string,
  I extends InitiliazerKeys,
  P extends ParameterSchema,
  T extends Terminator
> = {
  eventname: E,
  namespace?: N,
  initializer?: I
  parameters?: P,
  terminator?: T,
  callback: (
    params: { [parameter in keyof P]: ParameterTypesMap[P[parameter]]["type"] },
    setup: { eventname: E, namespace: N, initiliazer: I, terminator: T[number] }
  ) => any
}

However, each of these EscapeHandlerSettings should have its own generics because the parameters passed to the callback and setup depend on the generic parameters of that specific configuration.
For example, when the first parameter passed to the constructor is:
{
  eventname: "event1",
  namespace: "namespace1",
  initializer: "ESC",
  parameters: { attr1: "string?", attr2: "number" },
  terminator: ["A", "B", "C", "D"] as const,
  callback: (params, setup) => { }
}

This means that the params in the callback function should have the following type:
{
  attr1: string | undefined;
  attr2: number;
}

And the setup parameter should have the type:
{
  eventname: "event1";
  namespace: "namespace1";
  initializer: "ESC";
  terminator: "A" | "B" | "C" | "D";
}

I want to create a constructor for my EscapeHandler class that can accept multiple configurations of this type, where each configuration should have its own specific generics. Right now, I'm trying to make the class accept an indefinite number of these configurations, but each one should have its own types inferred based on the configuration passed.
Here is the class definition and an example of how it should be used:
class EscapeHandler<
  E1 extends string, 
  N1 extends string, 
  I1 extends InitiliazerKeys, 
  P1 extends ParameterSchema, 
  T1 extends Terminator,

  E2 extends string, 
  N2 extends string, 
  I2 extends InitiliazerKeys, 
  P2 extends ParameterSchema, 
  T2 extends Terminator

  E extends string[], 
  N extends string[], 
  I extends InitiliazerKeys[], 
  P extends ParameterSchema[], 
  T extends Terminator[]
> {
  constructor(...settings: [
    EscapeHandlerSettings<E1, N1, I1, P1, T1>,
    EscapeHandlerSettings<E2, N2, I2, P2, T2>?,
    ...EscapeHandlerSettings<
        E[number], N[number], I[number], P[number], T[number]
    >[] // <-- How can I make this infinite and allow each element to have its own generic types?
  ]) { }
}

usage:
new EscapeHandler(
  {
    eventname: "event1",
    namespace: "namespace1",
    initializer: "ESC",
    parameters: { attr1: "string?", attr2: "number" },
    terminator: ["A", "B", "C", "D"] as const,
    callback: (params, setup) => { }
  },
  {
    eventname: "event2",
    parameters: { attrA: "string?", attrB: "number?" },
    terminator: ["X", "Y", "Z"] as const,
    callback: (params, setup) => { }
  },
  {
    eventname: "event3",
    namespace: "namespace3",
    initializer: "OSC",
    parameters: { attrK: "string?", attrL: "number?" },
    terminator: ["X", "Y", "Z"] as const,
    callback: (params, setup) => { } <- is not inferring literally
  }
)

How can I define the class constructor so that each element passed to the EscapeHandler can have its own generic parameters, and the types for params and setup are properly inferred for each configuration?
An alternative I found was:
type EscapeHandlerSettings<
  E extends string[],
  N extends string[],
  I extends (undefined | InitiliazerKeys)[],
  P extends ParameterSchema[],
  T extends Terminator[],
> = (
    & { [K in keyof E]: { eventname: E[K] } }
    & { [K in keyof N]: { namespace: N[K] } }
    & { [K in keyof I]?: { initializer: I[K] } }
    & { [K in keyof T]: { terminator: T[K] } }
    & { [K in keyof P]: {
      parameters: P[K],
      callback: (
        params: { 
          [parameter in keyof P[K]]: ParameterTypesMap[P[K][parameter]]["type"] 
        },
        setup: any
      ) => any
    } }
)

But I couldn't figure out how to make the attributes optional. I tried to use the ? operator, but it didn't work. I also tried to use the Partial type, but it didn't work either. I'm not sure if it's possible to make the attributes optional in this case.

Don't create parameters for the nested type parameters. Simplify to just class EscapeHandler<S1 extends EscapeHandlerSettings<string, string, InitiliazerKeys, ParameterSchema, Terminator>, S2 extends EscapeHandlerSettings<string, string, InitiliazerKeys, ParameterSchema, Terminator>> {   constructor(...settings: [S1, S2]) { } }. Admittedly that doesn't solve the problem of accepting arbitrarily many parameters of different (sub)types.
